# How can I print a date using the current locale settings?

Tags: c, linux, date

I'm trying to write a C program on Linux that prints the current date. Here in Brazil I want it to print in dd/mm/yyyy format and in the US it would print in mm/dd/yyyy format.

I thought that the "%x" specifier for strftime was supposed to do the trick but its printing in mm/dd/yyyy format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){

  struct tm local_now;
  {
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    struct tm *tmp = localtime(&now);
    local_now = *tmp;
  }

  char buf[20];
  strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%x", &local_now);

  printf("%s\n", buf);

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the output I get from running the `locale` command:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_NAME=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=pt_BR.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Apparently the `LC_TIME=pt_BR.UTF-8` setting is being ignored?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Setting-the-Locale.html  setlocale command is your friend.  Can you not call it?  Plus, your locale is a mixture.

Comment: jim, you should convert that to an answer :) I didn't know about setlocale. BTW, its now printing `31-05-2015`. Is there an easy way to use slashes instead of dashes or would it be too much trouble?

Comment: I would use "%d/%m/%Y" as a format for strftime  (or whatever order suits the your needs) instead.

Comment: but if I do that then the gringos won't be getting the date in their preferred order. I guess I can live with the dashes then.

Comment: @hugomg, the behavior also depends on the locale which are installed on the system. If you do not have the locale files installed, then `setlocale()` might silently fallback to the default locale. Check return code in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strftime and all other locale-dependent functions use the "C" locale by default. In order to use the users locale you must explicitly call the [`setlocale`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setlocale.html) function during your program initialization:

```
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    // ...
}
```

If you pass the empty string to `setlocale` then it will choose the locale according to the standard locale environment variables (LC_ALL, LC_TIME, etc).